# When side loading mmpks to Field Map through the Iphone App Folder, paste is not an option

Tags: iphone, arcgis-field-maps, mobile-map-package

We are needing to side load some maps into Field Map. Most Iphones we simply download the map from a site we have then copy and paste it to the Field Map folder from the File App. On a few iphones the paste option is not there under the File App when we drill down to the Field Maps folder. plugging directly to a computer is not an option - has anyone else seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

For those with this same issue. After re-installing the app the 3rd time that seemed to fix the issue. Must have been bad installs the previous times.